# how do I ask an if argument on a specific field which in a list of objects that contain a list in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects in which every object is containing a list itself. how do I  get the the JellyFishID field or the Amount field for using an IF argument
(I'm currently using Foreach):`

```
 public static List<Report> DataSorted = new List<Report> {
            new Report() { IsGoldUser=true, Date=new DateTime(2016, 3, 12,11, 59, 33), IsBurningWater=true, Type=Type.Shore, ZoneID = 1 ,
                ReportDetails =new List<ReportDetail> { new ReportDetail() { Amount = Amount.Few, Jellyfish = new Jellyfish { JellyfishID = 1, Venom = Venom.Strong } }  }  },
            new Report() { IsGoldUser=true, Date=new DateTime(2016, 3, 12, 11, 59, 33), IsBurningWater=true, Type=Type.Shore, ZoneID = 1 ,
                ReportDetails =new List<ReportDetail> { new ReportDetail() { Amount = Amount.Few, Jellyfish = new Jellyfish { JellyfishID = 1, Venom = Venom.Strong } }  }  },
            new Report() { IsGoldUser=true, Date=new DateTime(2016, 3, 12, 11, 59, 33), IsBurningWater=true, Type=Type.Shore, ZoneID = 1 ,
                ReportDetails =new List<ReportDetail> { new ReportDetail() { Amount = Amount.Few, Jellyfish = new Jellyfish { JellyfishID = 1, Venom = Venom.Strong } }  }  },
            new Report() { IsGoldUser=true, Date=new DateTime(2016, 3, 12, 11, 59, 33), IsBurningWater=true, Type=Type.Shore, ZoneID = 1 ,
                ReportDetails =new List<ReportDetail> { new ReportDetail() { Amount = Amount.Few, Jellyfish = new Jellyfish { JellyfishID = 1, Venom = Venom.Strong } }  }  },

 foreach (var item in DataSorted)
        {

               if (item.ReportDetails....) //???I want here to Make an Argument about The Amount field or the JellyFishID field in the list above....

        }
```

Comment: Each `Report` can have multiple `ReportDetails`. Do you need to check against the first one? What exactly do you want to check?

Comment: only one for now... if its multiple I have to use another foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't describe exactly what you want to check, but with `LINQ to Objects` you have a lot of possiblities. At first, you need to reference the correct namespace with

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your source code file.

Now, if you want to check if any items of your list contains a jellyfish with a given ID, you can use:

```
if (item.ReportDetails.Any(t => t.Jellyfish.JellyfishID == 1)) //...
```

Additionally you can have conditions inside a `Where`-function to filter your list and search only for jellyfish with a few amount:

```
if (item.ReportDetails.Where(t => t.Amount == Amount.Few).
                       Any(t => t.Jellyfish.JellyfishID == 1)) //...
```

There is a lot of information avaliable about `LINQ`, a lot of examples are in the MSDN (for example [this intro page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx)), but there are alternatives like [this one: 101 Linq examples](http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/linq101-lambda.php). It even has a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Tnx just what I needed